# Cosa vuol dire "passarsela" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs

Nel racconto *Ferro* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Ma tornammo a valle coi nostri mezzi, e al locandiere, che ci chiedeva ridacchiando come **ce la eravamo passata**, e intanto sogguardava i nostri visi stralunati, rispondemmo sfrontatamente che avevamo fatto un’ottima gita, pagammo il conto e ce ne andammo con dignità.

Ho trovato il [significato di "passarsela" sul dizionario De Mauro](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/passarsela):

> condurre un’esistenza, stare, vivere

Ma questo non sembra avere senso nel contesto della frase sopra citata. Per questa ragione vi chiedo: qual è il significato di "passarsela" nel testo?

Dal contesto, immagino che il locandiere stesse chiedendo ai ragazzi se avevano passato una buona giornata o come era andata la gita, ma non sono sicura sul significato esatto dell'espressione. Si tratta di un uso di "passarsela" poco comune?

Per dare un po' più di contesto, aggiungo questo brano, dal quale si può capire che i due ragazzi avevano avuto dei grossi guai:

> Scendemmo in due ore, malamente aiutati dalla corda, che era gelata: era diventato un maligno groviglio rigido che si agganciava a tutti gli spuntoni, e suonava sulla roccia come un cavo da teleferica. Alle sette eravamo in riva a un laghetto ghiacciato, ed era buio. Mangiammo il poco che ci avanzava, costruimmo un futile muretto a secco dalla parte del vento e ci mettemmo a dormire per terra, serrati l’uno contro l’altro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Charo la tua interpretazione è corretta, e a mio avviso l'espressione è comune.

Si usa appunto "passare" per chiedere **come** una persona ha trascorso un certo periodo di tempo;

Prendo dalla [definizione di "Passare" del Treccani, punto 10](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/passare/):

> Trascorrere il tempo o un determinato periodo di tempo in qualche luogo, impiegarlo in qualche occupazione: [...]; **e con riferimento al modo**: *come hai passato il Natale?*; *p. qualche ora serena in compagnia*; *il malato ha passato una notte agitata, tranquilla*.

La definizione che hai trovato sul De Mauro mi sembra risponda a (sempre dal Treccani):

> Fam.: *passarsela bene*, vivere agiatamente, piacevolmente; *passarsela male*, essere in tristi condizioni economiche, vivere in mezzo a varie preoccupazioni.

Nel brano in questione non ci si riferisce a un periodo di tempo particolare (*come hai passato la giornata*, *come hai passato il Natale*, ecc.), ma assume un senso più generale, del tipo

*"come è andata?"* o *"vi siete divertiti?"* (Suggerimento di egreg).

Inoltre, rileggendo il testo credo che l'espressione del locandiere contenga anche una sfumatura maliziosa (la domanda è fatta ridacchiando).

Altra locuzione assai usata:

> Come te la passi?

Che è equivalente a chiedere "Come stai?"

Da notare inoltre che esiste anche:

> Ve la siete spassata?

Che significa "vi siete divertiti?" (derivato da *spasso*)

Comment: Sì, Riccardo: se la domanda del locandiere fosse stata "Come avete passato la giornata?" l'avrei capito perfettamente. Ma qui è (cerco di trasformarla al discorso diretto) "Come ve la siete passata?", espressione non familiare per me, eccetto quando ha il significato di "vivere, condurre un'esistenza" (quello del De Mauro), che credo di aver incontrato prima qualche volta (probabilmente in espressioni simili a quelle che hai riportato qui dal Treccani, ma non mi ricordo bene).

Comment: Allora mi chiedo, se dico a una persona "Come te l'hai passata?" interpretarà che gli sto domandando "Come hai passato la giornata?".

Comment: più che "Come te l'hai passata?" credo che sia più corretto (a naso) "come te la sei passata?"  ma una domanda così generica non sottointende (a mio avviso) che si stia parlando di un periodo specifico di tempo (la giornata), ma credo riguardi un tempo passato più indefinito.Il locandiere credo non chieda come se la sono passata ieri, ma come hanno passato il tempo in generale. Inoltre, rileggendo il testo credo che l'espressione del locandiere contenga anche una sfumatura maliziosa (la domanda è fatta ridacchiando).

Comment: Ah, sì, Riccardo: sicuramente è "come te la sei passata?": ho fatto confusione con gli ausiliari, ma nel testo di Levi si vede chiaramente che è "essere", per la presenza del pronome riflessivo.

Comment: Sì, la domanda è probabilmente maliziosa perché veramente quei due avevano avuto dei grossi guai e probabilmente il locandiere l'aveva intuito.

Comment: "Il locandiere chiede come hanno passato il tempo in generale": se, secondo te, questo è il significato dell'espressione, potresti aggiungerlo alla risposta?

Comment: @Charo No, il locandiere non chiede “come hanno passato il tempo”. È più “com'è andata?”, “Vi siete divertiti?” o qualcosa di simile.

Comment: Ah, capisco, @egreg, ma non mi sembra che sia questo quello che dice la risposta: "per chiedere come una persona ha trascorso un certo periodo di tempo".

Comment: @RiccardoDeContardi: Se il significato è quello spiegato da egreg, potresti riscrivere la risposta in modo un po' più chiaro, per favore?

Comment: In questo momento, questa risposta con due voti, ma con il commento di @egreg con anche due voti, mi crea confusione. Non metto in dubbio che sia una buona risposta, ma credo  sarebbe buono cercare di spiegare con un po' più di chiarezza la frase che dice "per chiedere come una persona ha trascorso un certo periodo di tempo". Se ho capito bene il commento di egreg (il locandiere non chiede "come hanno passato il tempo"), il senso è più "per chiedere a una persona com'è andata in un certo periodo di tempo", no?

Answer (score 0):

Se, rivedendo una persona dopo molto tempo, chiedo “Come te la sei passata?”, non sto davvero domandando un riassunto delle attività nel periodo in cui non ci siamo visti. Un modo piuttosto comune; potrebbe essere anche “Come ti è andata in questi anni?”, con significato del tutto analogo.

La risposta può essere “bene”, “abbastanza bene”, “non male”, “male” o qualcosa di simile.

Analogamente se rivedo qualcuno che so aver fatto qualcosa di particolare, come una passeggiata in montagna. In entrambi i casi la risposta breve può essere completata con qualche dettaglio, ma non è obbligatorio. Un po' come “How do you do?".

Nel caso presente, il locandiere sembra sapere che la gita non possa essere andata molto bene e sta dicendo velatamente che sa delle difficoltà, ma i ragazzi fanno finta di niente.

Comment: Ho aggiunto un brano alla domanda per dere un po' più di contesto. Immagino che fosse per il fatto di arrivare alla locanda il giorno dopo al previsto, forse anche per l'aspetto che avevano i ragazzi, non so... e non per il tempo.